# SilverStripe post news to social network

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, silverstripe, facebook-social-plugins

Is there any already made module to publish news articles from SilverStripe to Facebook / Twitter?

I have looked for something and found `pitchandtone/silverstripe-facebookpush` but I have some errors even when running `dev/build`.

I am stuck on this line:

> Set access token to response from this URL: (replaced with your app's id and secret)'*

Also, I think it is not compatible with my version 3.1.18 because the module is from 2012-2013.

I have created a Facebook app, so I have app id, app secret and user id.

Is there any existing SilverStripe module to publish news articles from SilverStripe to Facebook / Twitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that that module is so old, I would avoid it like the plague. Did you search for "Facebook" on SilverStripe addons? There are 4 pages of results with at least 2 promising looking ones on the first page of results.

Confused about which to pick? Always go for modules that have recent commits made to them. This gives dev's confidence they will be using something that is supported. Take the score on addons.silverstripe.org into account. This is an indication of how detailed you can expect that support to be with regard to docs etc (More here: http://www.silverstripe.org/software/addons/supported-modules-definition/). Simplicity is also key. If the module does several different things at once, it may well be very good at doing those, but it also means a steeper learning curve for new users of the module.

Good luck.